# Is a DDD entity hidden in my DDD Value Object?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, software-design

In my home project I faced a problem in determining a type of my domain object.

Domain: Bus Timetables

Bounded contexts: routing (public transport infrastructure, ctx1), timetable (scheduling, ctx2)

Objects:

- Station - describes a bus station
- Route(ctx1) - a set of stations (Route waypoints)
- Line (ctx1) - describes a bus line. Contains List.
- Schedule(ctx2) - a named set of departures from Route's waypoints.

For example: A Bus line 25A has two routes [{st1, st3, st20}, {st20, st15, st3, st1}] and 2 schedules (schedule 1 - route 1, sch2- r2)  attached to these 2 routes.

With no doubts I identified **Line** and **City** as a DDD entities, aggregate roots. In addition, I decided to put Routes into Lines, because they make no sense outside of the Line and theirs lifecycle == Line's lifecycle. Still looks good.

The next step is to define Schedule domain object. I wanted to separate it from the public transport infrastructure, so I put it in another context as an entity. The problem is that now I need to attach it to route, that has no identifier.

My ideas:

- **Put schedule into Route**. Why it is not an option: Line becomes fat; creates a ubercontext of ctx1 and ctx2
- **Make Route an entity**. Why it isn't an option (I think...): while it not hard to imagine route with some identifier (e.g. Name), it is hardly enough to imagine a Bus route outside of a Bus line.

Maybe I did something completely wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to think more about how you want to use your domain. In your example you already say you have a line, a line has route, and a line has schedules.

I would also expect that you want to ask route questions (like is st77 on this route) Or operations (stop s99 is closed for 2 weeks). That means route is an entity. with possibly your stops being value objects.

The aggregate root of route would be a bus line, like you said you can't image a route outside of a line. Which is exactly what an aggregate root means.

Furthermore the identifier of a route doesn't have to be a meaningfull name, it could have some random guid as a identifier. My computer as a serial number. Noone ever really talks about that serial number (I talk about a dell of type x) yet when i ordered it that's a very good number to identify and track that specific computer.

**update** also DDD is about describing/modeling your problem. it's about the journey descovering your problem domain. don't be too fixed in what it looks like but rather discover what it looks like when talking though the problem you are trying to solve (with your domain expert). Maybe you discover that routes and lines don't even matter just schedules & stops. (if the problem you were trying to solve if is finding when the next bus arives, lines seem to matter more if you are the bus company and need schedule actually driving the bus)

Comment: You said: ```and a line has schedules``` - that's a thing i want to avoid. I want my routing domain to know nothing about schedule domain. That means, `Schedule` entity must have a Route's idenifier. But if `Route` is an entity in `Line Aggreate Root`, i can't reference it while it is a part of Aggreate Root and the only possible reference here is a link between `Schedule` and `Line`. Am I right?

Comment: it's all 1 big domain (with possibly multiple aggregate roots). But a line, route and schedule seem very much interconnected. Your schedule/timetable is dependent on the route. So I don't see 2 bounded context happening here

Comment: +1  Excellent edit, Batavia.  It is so easy to get caught up in how "we" want to see it modeled, but the answer is likely already present if the stakeholder is asked.  The elements of the Ubiquitous Language very likely preexist the implementation.  Regardless of what makes the most sense from a development perspective, it should be driven by how the stakeholders view it.  If it is not, it makes the communication between the development team (which includes the domain experts/stakeholders) more difficult.